# regex to get particular values from a string

Tags: java, regex

A string outputs below result.

```
test179901034102 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open
test179901083723 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open
test179901153595 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open
test179901187836 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open

 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'filteredTable')]"));
 System.out.println( element.getText()); // returns the above string
```

My intention is to get the values `test179901034102 , test179901083723 e`tc as a list separately from the string.

How can i use regex to get the values(`test179901034102 , test179901083723)  from the below string

```
test179901034102 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open
test179901083723 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open
test179901153595 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open
test179901187836 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open
```

Comment: Did you try anything? You really should.

Comment: iam trying to apply regex...since am new to regex it takes more time to find a valid solution for this..thats why i decided to share here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^[^ ]+`.

**Example:**

```
String s = "test179901034102 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open\n" +
    "test179901083723 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open\n" +
    "test179901153595 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open\n" +
    "test179901187836 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^ ]+", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/aZYgvC/1

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 does not support regular expressions.
XPath 2.0 has some functions which support regular expressions: `matches(), replace(), tokenize()`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[matches(text(),'test\d+')"));
```

Comment: but that solutions does not work because the text will be dynamic generated ones..it should not start with 'test' all times

Comment: Please add this to your question description

Answer (score 0):

Please try this core java code and modify according to your platform

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
   String input="test179901034102 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open\n test179901083723 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open\n test179901153595 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open\n test179901187836 00:00:00:00:00:01 Open";

  Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("test[0-9]*");
  Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

  while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
  }

  Pattern pattern2=Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2}:){5}[0-9]{2}");
  Matcher m2 = pattern2.matcher(input);

  while (m2.find()) {
   System.out.println(m2.group(0));
  }

 }
}
```

Use https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output to try out regexes